# Tracking network (internet) packages in Windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, monitoring, packages, tracking

Is there a good application to track incoming and outgoing network packages for Windows 7?
In other words monitoring my PC's network traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For detailed packet monitoring, [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is probably what you want.

[image]

WireShark is free and open source.

If you'd like to see which applications are using your connection in detail, [NetLimiter Monitor](http://netlimiter.com) is great.

[image]

NetLimiter Monitor is freeware.

Both applications are Windows 7 compatible.